# Почему не работает object-fit?

Tags: html, css

```css
.f-img-block {
  background: red;
  height: 175px;
  width: 290px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.f-img-block img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="f-img-block">
  <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/images-4-17.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Почему картинка не заполняет все свободное место родителя. Смотрел в хроме. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Для картинки задайте "width: 100%"

Comment: добавьте `display: flex` блоку

Answer (score 4):

width и height должны быть заданы для изображения, а не обертки

```
.f-img-block {
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.f-img-block img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 175px;
  width: 290px;
}
```